# What chemical could be used as carbon monoxide scrubber?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, purification, gas-phase-chemistry

I am trying to produce nitrogen by passing air over a heated tube of coals. This leaves a mixture of $\ce{CO},$ $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{N2}.$ Only $\ce{CO}$ is unwanted in this case.

Could I use calcium hydroxide to scrub carbon monoxide out of the gas? What other substances could be effective?

edit: this is part of challenge to make other chemicals from natural resources, therefore i have to obtain nitrogen myself instead of buying it

Comment: If you just want pure nitrogen, locate your nearest specialty gas company. Cylinders of nitrogen are danged cheap. And any welding shop has pure argon if you just want something pretty inert.

Comment: Whole this is particularity bad and convoluted idea

Comment: CO could be absorbed in solution of copper(I) chloride  in ammonia or hydrochloric acid. ( almost insoluble in water ). But I am not sure about residual CO left and using the reagent may affect the intended nitrogen  usage, unless cleaned up.

Comment: @joncuster It is definitely the easiest and preferred way, but the OP may want just small volume. The whole cylinder may be "a cannon for a sparrow". It would help if the purpose was revealed, if he really needs nitrogen, or just a gas without oxygen. For the later, CO2 would be easier way.

Comment: It is an experiment done for the pleasure of doing it? OP please explain. Otherwise buy N2. And what about CO2? There should be some, although is easy to be scrubbed away.

Comment: it is. I was thinking of ways to make chemicals from sources found in the wild. Nitrogen could be used to turn charcoal mixed with potash into potassium cyanide at 1200°C, which hydrolyzes to give ammonia, as artifficial fertilizer (bucher process). carbon monoxide would shift the equillibrium the wrong way

Comment: Specify a) the quantity (volume at pressure x and temperature y) you need, b) check if you refer to CO as carbon monoxyde, because $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ normally is used to catch CO2 / carbon dioxyde.  c) Offer a realistic estimate about the highest concentration of CO acceptable for you.  d) An indication of the intended use of this purified gas could offer a second perspective if your estimate c) is reasonable or suggest an alternative more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Air reacting with charcoal will produce $\ce{N2},$ $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}.$ $\ce{CO2}$ will be absorbed by calcium hydroxide or sodium hydroxide.

However, $\ce{CO}$ cannot be absorbed at ordinary temperatures and pressures. Only at $\pu{200 °C}$ and $\pu{10 atm},$ it reacts with $\ce{NaOH}$ to produce sodium formate $\ce{HCOONa}.$

Finally, $\ce{CO}$ can be oxidized into $\ce{CO2}$ by passing over hot $\ce{MnO2}$ or $\ce{Fe2O3},$ and then be absorbed by a hydroxide.